# Pandas / sqlite3: Change part of pandas dataframe and replace in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

Experts,

I am struggling to find an efficient way to work with pandas and sqlite.

I am building a tool that let's users

1. extract part of a sql database (sub_table) based on some filters
2. change part of sub_table
3. upload changed sub_table back to
   overall sql table replacing old values

Users will only see excel data (so I need to write back and forth to excel which is not part of my example as out of scope).

Users can

- replace existing rows (entries) with new data
- delete existing rows
- add new rows

**Question:** **how can I most efficiently do this "replace/delete/add" using Pandas / sqlite3?**

Here is my example code. If I use `df_sub.to_sql("MyTable", con = conn, index = False, if_exists="replace")` at the bottom than obviously the entire table is replaced...so there must be another way I cannot think of.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np


#### SETTING EXAMPLE UP

### Create DataFrame
data = dict({"City": ["London","Frankfurt","Berlin","Paris","Brondby"],
            "Population":[8,2,4,9,0.5]})
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = pd.Index(np.arange(5)))

### Create SQL DataBase
conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")

### Upload DataFrame as Table into SQL Database
df.to_sql("MyTable", con = conn, index = False, if_exists="replace")

### Read DataFrame from SQL DB
query = "SELECT * from MyTable"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con = conn)

#### CREATE SUB_TABLE AND AMEND

#### EXTRACT sub_table FROM SQL TABLE
query = "SELECT * from MyTable WHERE Population > 2"
df_sub = pd.read_sql_query(query, con = conn)
df_sub

#### Amend Sub DF
df_sub[df_sub["City"] == "London"] = ["Brussel",4]
df_sub

#### Replace new data in SQL DB
df_sub.to_sql("MyTable", con = conn, index = False, if_exists="replace")
query = "SELECT * from MyTable"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con = conn)
```

Thanks for your help!

> Note: I did try to achieve via pure SQL queries but gave up. As I am not an expert on SQL I would want to go with pandas if a solution exists. If not a hint on how to achieve this via sql would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way around using SQL queries for this task.
With pandas it is only possible to read a query to a DataFrame and to write a DataFrame to a Database (replace or append).

If you want to update specific values/ rows or want to delete rows, you have to use SQL queries.
Commands you should look into are for example:
UPDATE, REPLACE, INSERT, DELETE

```
# Update the database, change City to 'Brussel' and Population to 4, for the first row 
# (Attention! python indices start at 0, SQL indices at 1)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('UPDATE MyTable SET City=?, Population=? WHERE ROWID=?',  ('Brussel', 4, 1))
conn.commit()
conn.close()

# Display the changes
conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")
query = "SELECT * from MyTable"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con=conn)
```

For more examples on sql and pandas you can look at
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases/